# setTimeout() doesn't work with jQuery(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, removeclass

I've got this piece of script here, where I'd like to slide up my ul element, then after the slide up executed, I'd like to remove the "open" class for CSS reasons. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp(500);
setTimeout(function(){
  var elementToRemove = jQuery(this).parent();
  elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
}, 500);
```

Comment: If you're intending to call the anonymous function after the slideUp animation has completed, use a callback instead of hardcoding a `setTimeout` timer. If you update your animation duration in the future, you wouldn't have to update `500` in two places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside you callback function refers to the global object and not the event target.

Two solutions:

Use arrow functions (which preserve the `this` context):

```
jQuery(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp(500);
setTimeout(() => {
  var elementToRemove = jQuery(this).parent();
  elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
}, 500);
```

Or save a link to the `this` object:

```
jQuery(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp(500);
let that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
  var elementToRemove = jQuery(that).parent();
  elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
}, 500);
```

Comment: Amazing! Didn't know about "arrow functions", thanks for letting me know!

Comment: should note arrow functions don't have full browser support

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass the context to the function

```
jQuery(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp(500);

var func = function(){
  var elementToRemove = jQuery(this).parent();
  elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
}
setTimeout(func.bind(this),500);
```

**Solution 2**

```
jQuery(this).parent().children("ul").slideUp(500);
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){
  var elementToRemove = jQuery(self).parent();
  elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery animations allow for an additional optional pararameter (a callback) called `complete` in the docs that will be executed once the animation is done. You can use it like this:

```
jQuery(this).parent()
            .children("ul")
            .slideUp(500, function(){
                var elementToRemove = jQuery(this).parent();
                elementToRemove.removeClass("open");
            });
```